# Why does my Heroku background script stop prematurely?

Tags: php, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I have a PHP script hosted in Heroku that sends messages to a list of users. Now I want to add a delay in-between those messages; something like a 6-minute gap between each message. So if there are 90 users, that script should run for 9 hours, in the background.

I tried calling this script using Ajax, so it runs in the background and adding `sleep(360);` inside the for loop, to get 6 mins delay. But it only works for approx 10 to 20 users; after that, it stops.

```
foreach ($users_list["users"] as $key => $value) {
        try{
            ....
            code for sending message
             .....

        }catch(Exception $e){
            continue;
        }
        sleep(360);
    }
```

Why does it stop? How can I get it to run for the full list of users?

Comment: Ajax doesn't make it run in the background because it's still running under Apache, you have to call it via something like `exec` or `shell_exec`  or even `CRON` here is  a background execution script I wrote [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php)  just be careful with using any end user data as part of a command line call.

Comment: Also I should mention that a lot of times PHP uses a separate `ini` config file for the command line, that may or may not have different extensions enabled.

Comment: Will this work in heroku?

Comment: I don't have that so I have no idea.

Comment: Can you access that via the command line ( SSH ) and run PHP?  for example could you do `php -v` in a SSH session.  Have you ever used `CRON` I never seen the `Heroku` thing, do they let you do CRON jobs etc

Answer (score 2):

Calling a script using AJAX doesn't call it in the "background" it just runs it Asynchronously from the page you are on. In other words it's still running in Apache, has any session data, and still bound by the timeout settings of PHP and Apache.

To run it truly in the background you can use something like [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Or if you are allowed to on your server you can call it by command line like with `exec` or `shell_exec`, there are a few other similar functions too, such as `popen`, `system` etc. They all do things in a slightly different way.

Some environmental stuff will be different and this may have a big impact on your code. For example a lot of stuff in `$_SERVER` is not set or has different information. Such as the servers IP address may not be in there, you won't have any session stuff. You won't be able to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` but can get the input data (form the command line call) from the `$argv` array, the first item being the files path, etc.

Basically you need to call it like this:

```
 exec('php -f "path/to/php/file.php" "arg1" "arg2"');
```

Calling it this way it will still be blocking, meaning it waits for execution of the called script.

To go one step further and make it non-blocking, you can add (on Linux)

```
exec('php -f "path/to/php/file.php" "arg1" "arg2" > /dev/null &');
```

The `&` at the end is the most important bit.

Now on Windows it's a bit of a different ballgame. I've had success using this:

```
$WshShell = new \COM('WScript.Shell');
$cmd = 'cmd /C php "path/to/php/file.php" "arg1" "arg2"';
$WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

Also on windows to run PHP with just `php` you have to add the path to the `php.exe` you want to use to the `path` environmental variable. Otherwise you have to use the full path to the `exe` instead of just `php`.

In either case you should be very careful about putting end user data in any command line call. There are two functions to sanitize it, but I try to just not put it in:

- [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)
- [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

I wrote a wrapper class for this you can find on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php)